# I have written a jQuery uploading plugin, but when I ran it, I got two times of running procedure

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is like below:

```
$('#upload-avatar').on('click', function(){
        $.upload({
            name: '<?php echo config('fileFormName') ?>[]',
            url: 'ec.php?obj=file&action=upload',
            accept: 'image/*',
            preview: '#avatar',
            success: function(imgUrl){
                console.log(imgUrl);
                $('#submit-avatar, #giveup-avatar').siblings('a').fadeIn('normal');
            }
        });
    });
```

When the first time I clicked the '#upload-avatar', the console logged once imgUrl of one line. But when the second time I clicked '#upload-avatar', the $.upload() ran two times and the console logged two times of two imgUrl lines, and they were different. So did the third time. Though it didn't obviously affect the result of imgUrl, but I would wanna know how to make it not run those nonsense times.

Comment: Can you include text of `$.upload` function at Question ?

Comment: Not understanding. There's a problem with 3 clicks producing 3 results?